# Angular 5 service variable value updating

Tags: angular, variables, service, updating

I can not update my angular service variable value.

I have two non-related components, and i want to send updated object from one to other one , using service . But I can't update object in service.

---

First component :

```
import { SoruService } from '../soru.service';
import { SoruModel, SecenekModel } from '../soruModel';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-first',
    templateUrl: './first.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./first.component.scss'],
    providers: [SoruService]
})
export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {
    public soruLst : [SoruModel];

    constructor( private soruServis : SoruService ) { }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.soruServis.getirSoruLst().subscribe( veri => {
            this.soruLst = veri as [SoruModel];
        })
    }

    //// MAKE SOME CHANGES ON "soruLst" locally 

    // Send updated 'soruLst' to service 
    updateSoruLst(){
        this.soruServis.updateSoruLst(this.soruLst);
    }

}
```

---

My Service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SoruModel, SecenekModel } from './soruModel';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

const metaJson = 'assets/data/Meta.json';

@Injectable()
export class SoruService {

    public sorular = [] as [SoruModel];

    constructor( private http:Http ) {
        this.sorular = [] as [SoruModel];
    }

    getirSoruLst() {
        return this.http.get(metaJson)
        .map(yanit => yanit.json())
    }

    updateSoruLst( soruLst : [SoruModel] ) {
             this.sorular = soruLst;
     }

    getSorular() : [SoruModel] {
        return this.sorular;
    }

}
```

---

Second Component :

```
mport { SoruService } from '../soru.service';
import { SoruModel, SecenekModel } from '../soruModel';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-second',
    templateUrl: './second.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./second.component.scss'],
    providers: [SoruService]
})
export class SecondComponent implements OnInit {
    public soruLst : [SoruModel];

    constructor( private soruServis : SoruService ) { }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.soruLst = this.soruServis.getSorular();
        console.log(this.soruLst);
    }
}
```

---

This is what i want to do :

1. in FirstComponent, get 'soruLst' from service and change it locally (Success)
2. in FirstComponent, send changed 'soruLst' to service (Success - updateSoruLst )
3. in Service, update 'sorular', in 'updateSoruLst' (Fail - it's not changing, only changing in function scope but i still can't read updated value) . I have problem with that :

   > updateSoruLst( soruLst : [SoruModel] ) {
   >       this.sorular = soruLst; }

"this.sorular" value doesn't change globally.

4. in SecondComponent, read updated 'sorular' from service ( Fail, still can't read updated value)

---

I think i must change my service , but could't find where must i change..

How can i update my object in service ?

Comment: Each component has SoruService in its providers. So each has its own dedicated instance of SoruService. The service should be provided in the NgModule, not in the components. Read the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection. And  while you're at it, also read the section about Http, and stop using the deprecated Http service.  Then read about RxJS, and about component interaction using a service: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As JB Nizet mentioned, you should provide your service in a higher level than the `FirstComponent` and the `SecondComponent`. That means `SoruService` should be provided

- either in your module class
- or in the parent component class of the above components if there are any

In that way both the components will share the same instance of the service and you will be able achieve what you need.
Assuming that you have your components in the root module of the app.
Remove the provider attributes from the component decorators and change your module like below.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FirstComponent } from './first.component';
import { SecondComponent} from './second.component';
import { SoruService } from '../soru.service';

@NgModule({
   imports: [
      BrowserModule
   ],
   declarations: [
       AppComponent,
       FirstComponent,
       SecondComponent
   ],
   providers: [
       SoruService
   ],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Also you can find a simple **rxjs Subject** example to share data among components using services in [here](https://stackblitz.com/github/SenalKumarage/ng-service-blitz).

Comment: That's great ! Thank you