# How can I listen for a Service variable change in a component in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, synchronous

I have a component with a button that triggers `showSummary()` when clicked that calls a service `Appraisal-summary.service.ts` that has a method `calc()`

```
showSummary(appraisal) {
  this.summaryService.calc(appraisal);
}
```

with service `Appraisal-summary.service.ts` :

```
calc(appraisal) {
  ...
  //a 'scores' array is created (synchronously)
  return this.scores;
}
```

How do I listen for the synchronous result `this.scores` to trigger a function in an unrelated component `summary.component.ts` (that has already been initialised) that will use  `scores`.

something like:
`summary.component.ts`:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  service.subscribe(scores => this.data = scores)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 5 service variable value updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49592546/angular-5-service-variable-value-updating)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to add a `Subject` inside your `Appraisal-summary.service.ts` like this:

```js
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

...
export class AppraisalSummaryService {
    // I am guessing scores is an array of type number
    public scoreSubject = new Subject<number[]>(); 
    
    calc(appraisal) {
      ...
      //a 'scores' array is created (synchronously)
      
      this.scoreSubject.next(this.scores); //emit the scores result
      return this.scores;
   }
}
```

And, in your other component, inside your `ngOnInit`, you want to listen to this result:

````js
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
....
export class YourOtherComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   private subscription: Subscription;

   constructor(private appraisalSummaryService: AppraisalSummaryService) {}

   public ngOnInit(): void {
     // you store your subscribe
     this.subscription = this.appraisalSummaryService.subscribe((scores: number[]) => {
       console.log(scores);
    });
   }
   
   public onDestroy(): void {
     // you need this in order to avoid a memory leak
     this.subscription.unsubscribe();
   }
   
}
```
````